# Testing for TeX boolean in Lua code

Tags: conditionals, luatex, lua

How can I test for a TeX boolean in Lua?

This kind of code doesn't work:

```
\newif\if@mypkg@someif

\begin{luacode}

   -- some lua code

   \if@mypkg@someif
      -- some more lua code
   \else
      -- another lua code
   \fi

   -- again some lua code
\end{luacode}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tex expansion happens before control is passed to lua. The following minimal example works.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newif\ifluaflag

% \luaflagtrue

\begin{luacode}
  print("before flag")
  \ifluaflag
    print("lua flag true")
  \else
    print("lua flag false")
  \fi
\end{luacode}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see a thing. This only outputs "test" in the PDF, using `lualatex` from TeXLive 2011.

Comment: Ah sorry, saw it in the output.

Comment: OK found the issue: `@` is redefined to other inside the luacode environment for some reason, so booleans using  `@` in their names won't work.

Comment: @Raphink: You can still access them with `\csname … \endcsname`.

Comment: @Andrey: Good to know. I've switched to names without `@`  though, and it helped ;-)

Comment: @Aditya You may want to update the minimal so it works. `print->tex.sprint` and place `luacode` after `begin{document}`

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: My intent was to show the output on the screen rather than in the pdf. I find it easier to debug when I see the output on the screen. So, using `print` instead of `tex.print` is intentional.